# Yaw angle calculation for a two-wheeled inverted pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

[Sorry, if this is a basic question. I'm a software engineer, learning mechanical engineering concepts by trying to build a self-balancing robot]

I'm unable to understand the yaw angle equation:
$\phi = (\frac RW) * (\theta_r - \theta_l)$
used in [NXT two-weheeled self balancing bot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19147-nxtway-gs--self-balancing-two-wheeled-robot--controller-design).

R - radius of the wheel.
W - Distance between the centres of the wheels.
$\theta_r$, $\theta_l$ - Rotation angle of the right and left wheels respectively.
$\phi$ - yaw angle.

[image: Coordinate system diagram for the two wheeled inverted pendulum model]

Comment: Hi @JJT. You can use math formatting by enclosing your expressions in `$...$`. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation. It will make your post much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaw angle is the rotation around a vertical axis.

It is easiest to understand if $\theta_l = 0$. In that case, the l wheel stays fixed and the r wheel travels in a circle around it. The distance the r wheel travels is $R*\theta_r$. The robot rotates through an angle $\phi = R/W*\theta_r$.

If $\theta_r > \theta_l > 0$, the robot drives around in a circle like a car turning. The r side travels farther. The center is on the l side of the robot. A line from wheel to wheel stays pointed at the center of the circle.

Each wheel drives around the same angle, $\phi = distance/radius$.

$\phi = R/R_r * \theta_r = R/R_l * \theta_l$.

For small angles, you can also calculate $\phi$ from the difference between the wheels' travel.

$\phi = \Delta  distance/\Delta radius = [(R*\theta_r) - (R*\theta_l)] / W = R/W *(\theta_r - \theta_l)$

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $R*\theta r$ and $R*\theta l$ for small $\theta$ as the linear displacements of the right and left wheel contact points with the ground and, without the wheels slipping, the difference causes a 'twisting' of the body over the wheel separation, $W$ in the vertical axis (yaw) as the wheels independently turn one direction or another.

The derivation comes simply comes from writing the trigonometric equalities - just draw the triangles, and realize that for small angles, $\theta$ that $ sin\theta = \theta$.